# What does it mean to ask isight to wait for the output file?

Tags: abaqus, isight

I used Abaqus in isight.
But it's doesn't work.
So I need your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tamAV.gif)

How can I solve this error?
I haven't been able to solve this problem for days.
Answer me, please. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missing file `test-3.dat`.

Also check the log for other missing files.
I assume you might have started the program at the wrong working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I think I can solve this problem.

But I have another problem.

"Error in dat file at line 81. **ERROR: in keyword *NODEOUTPUT, file "test.inp", line 4113: Unknown"

Do you happen to know anything about this error?

Anyway, thank you for your answer.